# Do email placeholders affect anything, and which kind should I use?

Tags: user-behavior, input-fields, placeholder

I'm going to have a small box on my website where visitors can input their email address to subscribe to my website newsletter. It looks like this, and will have a light text placeholder in the box where users enter their email.

[image]

Does it make a difference what the placeholder is, as far as what the user does? Also, what placeholder should be used? Should it be a generic one like `someone@domain.com`, or should it be related to my domain name? Also, does using the term `domain.com` seem confusing for some users, and if it does, what should I use for a generic email address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would discourage you from using "technical" terms. Misusing placeholders can cause *accessibility issues*, confusion, and violate the HTML5 spec.

It's important to note that placeholders are not [substitutes for labels](http://www.pardot.com/faqs/best-practices/placeholders-and-labels/).

I would encourage you to do 3 things.

**1. Shorten the copy**

"Sign up for news and updates" would do just fine. "Urgent" makes it seem scary, which isn't good unless you want to scare users into signing up.

**2. Use `you@example.com`**

Explicitly addressing users with "you" transfers ownership.

**3. Explicitly label the field with `email` or `email address`**

Hope that helps.

Comment: I forgot about example.com. This way, if they actually put that in, they go to the reserved example.com website instead of domain.com, which is for purchasing domains.

Comment: "Explicitly addressing users with "you" transfers ownership.". Great point!

Comment: Thank you both. @PhoenixLogan I forgot about that, to be honest, but upon doing a little poking around, it seems like everyone uses it. Feel free to edit my answer to reflect your change!